# how to set the attribute of a node in java for Neo4j Node

Tags: java, neo4j

I am trying to set a property for a node in Neo4j using java api.
Currently i am doing it as below :

```
tx.begin();
Node node = db.findNode(label,key,value);
node.setProperty("k",11);
tx.success();
```

How ever when i start the process once again, and try to retrieve this key or see, for the value in that particular node, i cannot see the key being present. How to proceed from this?

Answer (score 3):

[Transaction.success](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html#success--) only *marks* a transaction as successful. The transaction is not actually committed until [Transaction.close()](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html#close--) is called.

The [Transaction](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/Transaction.html) JavaDocs states the following:

> Here's the idiomatic use of programmatic transactions in Neo4j
>   starting from java 7:
>
> ```
> try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )  {
>     // operations on the graph
>     // ...
>
>     tx.success();
> }
> ```

That idiom uses a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement to ensure that `tx.close()` will be called automatically when the statement is exited (even if due to an exception). Your transactional code should follow suit.

For example:

```
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    Node node = db.findNode(label, key, value);
    node.setProperty("k", 11);
    tx.success();
}
```